# PHP routing and file access

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

I'm stuck with:

1. Should I use PHP routing with having in *.htaccess* written something like this:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
   ```

   and after this to parse the url like any MVC framework?

   *Note: I like the idea of this but i believe is too much to write it by myself, so well, should i trust the small frameworks like [klein](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php) and [slim](http://www.slimframework.com/)?*
2. Should I write rules in *.htaccess* for some public folders and just block access to private folders?

   *Note: About this I think its more powerful and more flexible when we are really talking about file access control.*

Also I want to mention that I'm not using the MVC pattern and everything I stated its based on my poor knowledge, so I want you to prove me wrong or say where I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Well, for my part, I wouldn't want my app to depend too heavily on .htaccess rules.  I use a simple ruleset like you've got in option 1, and then I let most of my routing be handled by the framework.  I use Klein every day and like it a lot.  It is powerful and reliable, but the codebase is relatively small, so if I really need to I can get under the hood and see what's going on.  I know some people who use and recommend Slim as well, though I haven't used it much myself.  Writing your own routing code in PHP is pretty simple to get started, but there are lots of edge cases you'll run into.

If you depend heavily on .htaccess, you can run into a few issues.  First .htaccess is parsed recursively, so Apache has to check every subdirectory down the tree for .htaccess files.  Some .htaccess rule down the chain could actually override your logic, and create unintended side-effects.  I don't think Nginx, or some of the other web servers out there even support .htaccess, so you're locking yourself into Apache.  Some hosting providers block use of .htaccess either completely, or in part.  Personally, I think routing logic will be easier to understand, and therefore maintain by future developers, if it's written in the language of the app, instead of .htaccess rules.

Lastly, I would caution against abandoning the MVC pattern.  If your domain logic (Model) bleeds into the rest of your app, you or the poor sucker who inherits your code will be in for a world of hurt.  If it's a small enough app, combining the Controller and View mightn't be catastrophic, but most apps grow.  Even if you don't follow strict MVC, follow some internally consistent pattern, and separate your concerns.  Regardless, my vote would be for a microframework with a minimal .htaccess rule, for ease of maintenance, ease of development, portability, and possible even performance (.htaccess can cause performance issues if over used enough, because of the recursion thing I mentioned).